# catch (Exception ex) not displaying MessageBox message for event

Tags: c#, messagebox, ex

So I'm coding a write to function and need the Exception ex to display a warning message that the txtFileContents.Text area is blank and needs to contain some text before the write to function can occur.

Here is my code...

```
private void btnWriteFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 //The saveFileDialog1 function allows the "Write" function to be used to save text to a file or create a new file when saved.
 if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
     //The "try"-"catch" block is used to allow the code to open a directory or file source for the user to browse.
     try
     {
         txtFilePath.Text = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
         StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(txtFilePath.Text);
         sw.WriteLine(txtFileContents.Text);
         sw.Close();
     }
     //The below code in the "catch" end of the code block will prompt the user to enter some text if nothing is entered.
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.Message);
     }
}
```

Do I need to add a specific `MessageBox.Show` command line and how would I do that?

I have tried re-wording the `Console.WrieLine("Exception: " + ex.Message);`

To include the error message inplace of the "exception" wording and nothing happens.
I have also tried adding a separate MessageBox.Show line and that didn't execute an error either.
I'm new to coding and am trying my hardest to get this right.

Comment: *Console*  doesn't plot a `MessageBox`, instead it writes to - well - `Console`. If you want any forms-element like a `MessageBox`, then yes, you need `MessageBox.Show`.

Comment: If you want to show a message box, you need to use `MessageBox.Show`, yes. You should validate the `FileName` property in your code instead of blindly using it and catching an exception. Since you are a new programmer: if the code you wrote doesn't work as you thought it would, add a breakpoint (F9) and use "Step Into" debugging (F11) to see where the code execution path leads you to understand where and why your code stops doing what you wanted it to do.

Comment: Thank you @MakePeaceGreatAgain, I am aware that Console.WriteLine is to write to the console, but how would I change it? Would simply code as this work? MessageBox.Show("Exception: Please enter some text to be written to the file that you wish to write to." + ex.Message);

Comment: @Benjamin I encourage you to try it :) The worst that can happen is that the code doesn't work - and then you use debugging to find out why.

Comment: Thanks @LWChris, I'll go back and have another look at the debugger to see what's going on and where.

Comment: MessageBox.Show("Exception: Please enter some text to be written to the file that you wish to write to." + ex.Message) - Tried this and sadly nothing changed, looking through code and trying to debug and see why. Thank you for the assistance thus far all, really appreciate it.

Comment: I can't imagine `MessageBox.Show` to do *nothing*. There must be some messagebox appearing somewhere. Maybe a different screen? Maybe hidden by another dialog?

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain, I'm not sure either. I think maybe it's the Click event and that I possibly need to add 'if' and 'else' factors to my code to better execute the exception. I'm going to keep investigating and will update as I go. The (F11) "Step Into" doesn't show the code that I added break points too, not sure why either.

Comment: @LWChris, to answer your response better, You should validate the FileName property in your code instead of blindly using it and catching an exception. I'm making a write to app that allows you to save a new file with the content entered into a text space, which is where I'm trying to catch the exception. Therefore I'm not able to declare the FileName. Also how do I change the text to grey the commands like you guys?

Comment: you can format code in comments using back-ticks like so \`my code comes here \`.

Comment: What LWChris wanted to point is, that you should **avoid** the exception in the first place, instead of using it for something normal like invalid user-input. So instead of relying on the exception in order to validate your input, check *if* the textbox contains any characters.

Comment: Having said this, your problem probably is, that the exception is never thrown. This can easily be validated by using your debugger, putting a breakpoint into the `Console.WriteLine`-line and see if it gets hit.

Comment: On top of the Button Click Handler, add `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFileContents.Text)) { MessageBox.Show("No content to write"); return; }` -- If the string cannot contain just spaces, change in `string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFileContents.Text.Trim())`. Or any other logic that fits -- Assuming a WinForms application. Add the relevant tags that specify the UI Platform

Comment: @Jimi, Thank you so much for your help. The `(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFileContents.Text)) {MessageBox.Show("No content to write"); return;` code you mentioned worked and now I get an error message is now displayed asking for text input. I would also like to say a big "Thank you" to all that commented it was very helpful information indeed and I have had some success with `debug` for other issues.